# Why, after migration, are edits to question not reflected in new site?

Tags: support, edits, migrated-questions

Compare those two questions:

1. [Accessing the internal phone memory by swapping out the SIM card [migrated]](https://superuser.com/questions/418556/accessing-the-internal-phone-memory-by-swapping-out-the-sim-card?noredirect=1)
2. [Accessing the internal phone memory by swapping out the SIM card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22457/phone-has-been-stolen-will-it-be-possible-to-read-its-internal-memory)

The first question was asked on superuser.com. Later it was migrated to android.stackexchange.com. Then the original question was edited.

**Why the edit was not reflected in destination question?** Is it a bug or feature?

Also, is the question in new location locked? I cannot see the 'edit' link underneath, even if I see it under every other question.

Comment: For some time I could not see the 'edit' link on the question in Android SE. But now, after edits from Community♦ user, it is visible.

Comment: A missing edit link on a non-locked posts means that there is an edit pending on the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edits aren't reflected because they are separate entities in the database (or even separate entities in separate databases).

The original question will have been locked when it was migrated preventing further changes - there's no "edit" link on migrated question.

In this case, the edit was in progress while the question was being migrated.

Moderators **do** have an edit link on migrated posts. However, I can't see a moderator *starting* an edit after the post was migrated. It might be the case that moderators are allowed to save an edit in progress while normal users can't.

Comment: It is locked, however moderator has edited it - probably moderators can edit locked questions and he didn't even notice.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I just checked the question and saw that. However, I'd still go for caching. It looks like Random was editing to clean it up prior to migration, but Sathya jumped in and migrated it anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I expect they are separate entities in DBs, but this kind of situation should not happen. Original question's edit should either be impossible or somehow synchronized.

Comment: I also wonder, if migrated question is locked for edits?

Comment: @Tschareck migration cause automatic lock of the whole question to prevent voting, answers, comments or edits - no point to do any of these as the question is no longer there. You can see it in the [revisions](http://superuser.com/posts/418556/revisions). Either Chris is right and the editor started the edit before the migration and lock took place then had the grace period, or was able to do that being a moderator. There is 2 minutes difference between the lock and edit.

Comment: @Tschareck - See update

Answer (score 1):

> Why the edit was not reflected in migrated question?

Reflecting the edits in the source site (the site where the migration has been done) doesn't make sense, as the question in the source site is deleted, at some time.

[image: screenshot]

Judging from the screenshot, taken from *Drupal Answers*, that happens a month after the question is migrated.

For the reason I said before, synchronizing the questions would require code that, IMO, it is not worth the time spent to write it. It should be considered that most of the users are taken to the question on the destination site, when clicking (on the source site) on a link to a migrated question. This is what happens when you click on https://superuser.com/questions/418556/accessing-the-internal-phone-memory-by-swapping-out-the-sim-card. Only moderators on the source site are not automatically directed to the destination site; if I click on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28906/how-do-i-use-require-once I am not redirected to *Stack Overflow*, but a user that is not moderator would be automatically redirected, if the link doesn't include "?noredirect=1" at the end of the link.
It is still possible to click on a link to get back to the question posted on the source site, but at that point the users have already seen the updated question, and its answers; it would not make sense to reflect the changes in the source site.